# While attempting to build telegraf on OpenBSD 6.4, gmake said:

Tags: openbsd, telegraf

I have followed the instructions from this page but gmake fails.
Am I missing a dependency?

https://www.tumfatig.net/20180905/running-telegraf-openbsd

dep ensure -vendor-only
SIGSYS: bad system call
PC=0x485670 m=9 sigcode=0

goroutine 305 [syscall]:
syscall.Syscall(0x25, 0xffffffffffff4f73, 0x9, 0x0, 0xd95448, 0xa58ce0, 0xc0000541b0)
        /usr/local/go/src/syscall/asm_unix_amd64.s:19 +0x5 fp=0xc0006a96e8 sp=0xc0006a96e0 pc=0x485645
github.com/golang/dep/vendor/golang.org/x/sys/unix.Kill(0xffffffffffff4f73, 0x9, 0xd95448, 0xa58ce0)

Comment: Update or reinstall [Go](http://ports.su/lang/go,-main) and try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I did a pkg_add of dep, gmake was able to build telegaf.

Or perhaps my attempts to build telegraf failed because I had not been in the $GOPATH/src/github.com/golang/dep directory when I checked out the telegraf source.

Case closed.

Answer (score 0):

upcoming `OpenBSD 6.5` has a package of `telegraf`.

luckily, it's low on dependencies and the one it uses seem to be "backward" compatible.

**this is not recommended for production use**

so there is a simple way to install `telegraf` on `OpenBSD 6.4`:

```
ln -s /usr/lib/libc.so.92.5 /usr/lib/libc.so.95.0
ln -s /usr/lib/libpthread.so.25.1 /usr/lib/libpthread.so.26.1
pkg_add https://ftp.openbsd.org/pub/OpenBSD/snapshots/packages/amd64/telegraf-1.9.0.tgz
```